# Getting Dot instead of Hyphen in RASA chat response

Tags: python, nlp, chatbot, rasa-nlu, rasa

My domain.yml file content look like below :

utter_xyz

`-`

text: "Which of the below you will choose : \n - Option1\n - Option2"

I want chatbot response like below:

#### Expected

Chatbot should utter :

```
Choose query on below topics : 
- Option1
- Option2
```

#### But, chatbot is uttering like below instead of hyphen,i am getting dot

Choose query on below topics:

- Option1
- Option2

Please Help

Comment: are you talking about a specific channel (web chat? telegram?)?

Comment: Front end is Angular JS .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be dependent on whatever frontend you use, not Rasa itself. For example, that is Markdown formatting, which is what the rasa-webchat uses to render lists. If you want to change that you'd have to change the code in the frontend or choose another frontend that outputs differently.